# Completing the square with this polynomial?

Tags: calculus, integration, polynomials, indefinite-integrals, completing-the-square

$$\int \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{4x^2+4x+17}}\,dx$$

So far I have only worked with polynomials of the type $x^2$, not $Ax^2$ what should I do to complete the square in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sqrt{4x^2+4x+17}=2\sqrt{x^2+x+\frac{17}4}=2\sqrt{(x+\frac12)^2+4}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: Or $4x^2+4x+17=4x^2+4x+1+16=(2x+1)^2+16$.

Comment: @martycohen good answer too